# How can I get images floated to the left of other definition list elements?

Tags: html, css

How can I get these `dd` images floated next to the `dt` and other `dd` elements in a `dl`?

Here's what I'd like:

[image: screenshot]

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmFcs/), and here is the markup:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Bacon ipsum</dt>
  <dd class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" /></dd>
  <dd>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet pork chop magna pork, tempor in jowl ham labore rump tenderloin pariatur pancetta tri-tip pork loin. Spare ribs meatloaf ground round chicken, non esse cow. </dd>
  <dt>Irure Jowl</dt>
  <dd class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/101/100" width="100" height="100" /></dd>
  <dd>Irure jowl non, chicken dolor veniam id in shoulder voluptate. Eu fugiat jowl, sunt drumstick id ad shankle shank aliquip bresaola aliqua reprehenderit. Fugiat shank pariatur strip steak laborum pork chop. Beef ribs aliquip fugiat, shankle id pork loin.  </dd>
  <dt>Biltong labore turkey</dt>
  <dd class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/1002" width="100" height="100" /></dd>
  <dd>Biltong labore turkey swine dolor short ribs minim. Fugiat beef consectetur, sirloin do ham meatloaf hamburger pariatur jowl swine ham hock.</dd>
</dl>
```

And the CSS:

```
dt
  { margin: .75em 0 .25em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

dd
  { margin: .25em 0;
    }

dd.img
  { margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
    }

img
  { border: solid #666666 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    }
```

If I just float the images left, the `dt` is above the image; but then I can't float the `dt` into the correct position.

What's the cleanest and most semantic way to do this type of layout?

Comment: Where did the screenshot come from?

Comment: Use tables! .... No just kidding.

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure?

Comment: I couldn't resist using baconipsum.com either.  I made the screenshot; mostly in Photoshop.  Yes, I can change the HTML; I'm certainly looking for the tidiest solution overall.

Comment: There's also Corporate Ipsum (if you're on OSX): http://doubleforte.net/widgets/corporate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** 
http://jsfiddle.net/PkwaP/

```
/* only showing the additions */
body { min-width: 400px; } /* change to appropriate value */
dt { clear: left; margin-left: 116px; }
dd { margin-left: 116px; }
img { float: left; margin-top: -1.25em; margin-right: 10px; }
```

added margin-left to dd to avoid the text wrap on the image. adding a min-width to the body will avoid wrapping on the dt in most cases.

I cannot spend any more time on this question tonight. If it is not solved I will take another crack at it in the morning.

Good Luck

Comment: Closer than sandeep, though still not _exactly_ what the OP's image shows.

Comment: @Matt, by exactly are we referring to minor typographic details, or is my positioning off? @thirtydot, oh perhaps that is what Matt meant.

Comment: @thirtydot, who puts a <br> inside a <dt> ?

Comment: @Matt, the text wrapping is a valid problem. However, I think it is valid to note that @thirtydot's fiddle included a <br> inside his <dt>

Comment: @thirty's has the exact same problem as yours.

Comment: @matchew: The point I was trying to make is that if you have a long title that goes onto two lines (or a title with a line break), the image moves down instead of staying at the top. That might not be a problem if all the titles will be short, but who knows?

Comment: @thirtydot, you are correct. My apologizes. I have updated my answer. Thank you both for the input. It was much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling for a while with the massive red herring that was your HTML..

I decided to forget about using a `dl`. I did experiment with it (a lot), but I couldn't come up with anything that I deemed acceptable. So, I've changed to a `ul`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/8xPRZ/1/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
        <h4>Bacon ipsum</h4>
        <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet pork chop magna pork,  tempor in jowl ham labore rump tenderloin pariatur pancetta tri-tip pork  loin. Spare ribs meatloaf ground round chicken, non esse cow.</p>
    </li>

    ..
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li > img {
    border: solid #666 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    float: left
}
li > h4, li > p {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em
}
li > h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0
}
```

Comment: I'd use a `<p>` instead of a `<span>` but this is pretty much what my attempt ended up as.

Comment: @mu is too short: So would I. I've updated my answer, thanks. I'd spent a little too much time looking at this one.

Comment: You might be able to construct some sort of horrific monstrosity with absolute positioning and the original `<dl>` if you were so inclined. Some variation on this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SmFcs/4/ (No, I'm not putting that down as an answer, I feel dirty enough just from coming up with the idea).

Comment: @mu is too short: I considered that, but rejected it for the reason I gave @matchew: http://jsfiddle.net/SmFcs/5/

Comment: @thirtydot, +1 this works well, but I think the final answers boils down to should this be a <dl> or a <ul> and without content the choice becomes unordered list. Thanks again for the input on my answer, I believe I do have a working answer, but I am always up for critiques.

Comment: @matchew: I agree that you do have a valid answer, and I already gave you a +1 :) It just has that minor downside with longer titles, which might not even be a problem.